# What happens when a Jace, the Mind Sculptor is played in an unspecific format?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I'm playing casual without a specific format but I'm still trying the rules, what happens when a [Jace, the Mind Sculptor](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Jace%2C%20the%20Mind%20Sculptor) is played?  It is banned from Modern but not from Legacy.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking here. Can you please explain why you think Jace would behave differently in different formats?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your and your opponent either agree to a format (in which case, you follow the restriction of that format), or you agree to use your own format (in which case you get to decide what cards are allowed in it). The rules have no say in this.

Answer (score 4):

Formats regulate what cards are allowed in decks and sideboards in the first place.  At the point at which you have already started to play with those cards in the decks, then either the cards are allowed or the game is invalid.